# Open images in a Modal way, using Struts2 and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, struts2, modal-dialog

I want to try to open all the images from my website on click in a Modal way. I'm using Struts2, Bootstrap. Show me please the correct way, some example?

this is my code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <s:iterator value="galleryList" var="galleryTemp">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
         <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href=""><img src='userfiles/images/<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.imageName}" />'  class="thumbnail"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.id}" />"  alt="body img" />
            </a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.id}" />" tabindex="-1" role="image" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

         <img src='userfiles/images/<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.imageName}" />' class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" alt="body img" />
           </div>
     <div class="caption">
<center><h4><s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.description}" escapeHtml="false"/></h4>                   </center>
    </div>
   </div>    
 </div> 
</s:iterator>
</div>
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: [look at this, here is my example of code](http://tnkscr.net/xNukmL.jpg)

Comment: Put a code to the question, not image.

Comment: done, introduced the code what I'm using

Comment: when I click, my modal window is showing the image, but in another div, I mean the image is opened [in this div](http://tnkscr.net/Qwtm34.jpg), sure without some text, just image, and white background

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <div class="row">
    <s:iterator value="galleryList" var="galleryTemp">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
         <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="#"><img src='userfiles/images/<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.imageName}" />'  class="thumbnail"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.id}" />"  alt="body img" /></a>
         </div>
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.id}" />" tabindex="-1" role="image" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <div class="caption">
             <center><h4><s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.description}" escapeHtml="false"/></h4>                   </center>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <img src='userfiles/images/<s:property value="%{#galleryTemp.imageName}" />' class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" alt="body img" />
            </div>
           </div>    
          </div> 
       </div>
    </s:iterator>
</div>
```